# What kind of maps are in this channel packed image?

Tags: texturing

I've tried to provide a good diagram of what I think these maps could be but im not entirely sure I got it right. Can anyone identify what texture maps are in the RGB channels specifically, or correct me if im wrong? I've labeled them but again, Im not 100% sure thats what they are.
[image]

Comment: It says in the picture: R is Alpha (transparency), G is Roughness, and B is Specularity. Does that answer your question?

Comment: No I made this diagram of what I think they could be. I've only been provided with the Normal, Diffuse and RGB MAP. After separating the channels in the RGB I get the 3 textures here.

Comment: Where did you get it from? Is there any information? Channel packing can have different maps. One example for a method is RMA, which stands for **R**oughness, **M**etallic, **A**mbient Occlusion, but I strongly doubt that your RGB map falls into this category (I don't believe the leaves are metallic, for example).

Comment: This specific texture was extracted directly from Fortnite.

Comment: So I guess this isn't even a Blender question... maybe there are some Fortnite forums where people have experience with extracting data from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have them all right except:
GREEN = ambient occlusion
BLUE = subsurface scatter

Sometimes external game textures have the Green or Blue channel inverted, so you need to invert them back in Blender if you want to visualize them correctly. The reason why I think Green is AO is because there are a lot of pbr mobile games that use this channel for that instead of the Red channel.
When you mention green in your current setup could be roughness, I agree if I could see how the plant looks "in-game". Since I don't have that, I'd still say this asset is missing the AO map.

Comment: How would you incorporate the subsurface scatter on a plane object? I know you can use translucency maps but arent those usually like a lighter green/orangish tint for foliage such as this? Examining the extracted model. It does in fact use a bunch of planes to represent these branches. Im going to see if I can pull some shots from "in-game" for better comparison.